# Local Server not loading in Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I have `laravel` app which is running in my windows local server. This laravel app is running `port:80`. I want to load this app in my **Ubuntu VirtualBox**.

My IP Config:

```
IPv4 Address   : 192.168.8.157
Subnet Mask    : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.8.1
```

I have config my `virtualbox` as `Bridged Adapter`. In my `/etc/hosts` (ubuntu virtualbox), I have this :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   asus

192.168.8.157   v2.my.local
```

I have made a hello word app (node.js) in my local windows which is running on port `:3000`, and it is running in my `VirtualBox` by typing `v2.my.local:3000`, but if I type `v2.my.local` on my `VirtualBox`, it is not working (although app is running on windows local machine). it says:

```
This v2.my.local page can’t be found
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be windows firewall blocking connections via port 80. turn off firewall and try it, if it works. Start windows firewall and add firewall rule to allow connections via port 80. If your windows version is 10 then, it will block all virtual box related connections. make sure to add correct rules.